# Javascript Alert Function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have attempted to produce Javascript Alert functions for my website so that they would pop up,however for some unidentified reason-they do not work.I have tested my code with W3C Validator,which resulted in 3 warnings,one of which said I had missed a body tag,yet I do not see any error within my code.Please assist?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Example 1 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="2">Example 2 Answer</button><br>
<button onclick="3">Example 3 Answer</button><br>
<button onclick="4">Example 4 Answer</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("10/63");
}
function 2() {
  alert("13/10");
}
function 3() {
  alert("37/30");
}function 4() {
  alert("4/21");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: upvote for this little boy with big dreams

Comment: It's appreciated-thanks.

Comment: Hmmm,...still not working-as always,only the first fraction,10/63 is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for old browsers:

```
       <script language="text/javascript">
```

Function names can not start with numbers, fix that also.

Edit:

For HTML4

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
```

For HTML5

```
       <script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have just a number as a function name. Change it like following:

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("10/63");
}
function a2() {
  alert("13/10");
}
function a3() {
  alert("37/30");
}
function a4() {
  alert("4/21");
}
```

And the HTML should change like this:

```
<p>Click the button.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Example 1 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a2()">Example 2 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a3()">Example 3 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a4()">Example 4 Answer</button>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5a30ca32/)

Comment: It does work,but then again-only the first button works-10/63.The rest are static.

Comment: Yup-I did,however someone already answered my question.Thanks,though!

Answer (score 1):

Function names can't begin with digits. If you copy paste your following function in the console you will get `unexpected number` reference.

```
function 2() { alert("4/10"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c1pcc4xv/

```
 <form action="">
     <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Add"/>
</form> 
//script
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myButton');
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
alert("yo");
});
```

make your code simple, and avoid function names starting with number....Hope it helps

Comment: Perhaps,perhaps.however,I need multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tallrye/40aovzp6/)

Yes, you can not use just numbers as a function names. And also, wrap it in the head tag, define your function before calling it in your html.

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("10/63");
}
function myFunction2() {
   alert("13/10");
}
function myFunction3() {
   alert("37/30");
}
function myFunction4() {
  alert("4/21");
}
```

Comment: Thank You-It's appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. When you open my jsfiddle, please note that on the left panel, I've selected "No wrap -in <head>" option.